# Operator Overloading unexpected result

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I cannot understand why the unary - operator is not working. I am sure I am missing some concept. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Distance {
   private:
      int feet;             // 0 to infinite
      int inches;           // 0 to 12
   public:
      // required constructors
      Distance(){
         feet = 0;
         inches = 0;
      }
      Distance(int f, int i){
         feet = f;
         inches = i;
      }
      // method to display distance
      void displayDistance() {
         cout << "F: " << feet << " I:" << inches <<endl;
      }
      // overloaded minus (-) operator
      Distance operator- () {
         return Distance(-feet, -inches);
      }
};

int main() {
   Distance D1(11, 10), D2(-5, 11);

   -D1;                     // apply negation
   D1.displayDistance();    // display D1

   -D2;                     // apply negation
   D2.displayDistance();    // display D2

   return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
F: 11 I:10
F: -5 I:11
```

And I expected it to be -11 -10 and 5 and -11

Don't know where am I missing a concept. BTW I found it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/unary_operators_overloading.htm)

Comment: `int n = 5; -5; cout << n << endl;` Would you expect that to print 4?

Comment: @juanchopanza no!  I would expect it to print 5 and -5

Comment: I like how on that web site they show the exact same output you are showing. Apparently they copied it from the console and it never occurred to them this output shows the discussed operator overloading did not work. Another example of why one [should not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/11683) use bogus tutorials.

Comment: Good example how shitty tutorialspoint is. Explaining it wrong, showing it wrong and stating thats how it works.

Comment: Ahh! I feel for new people like me searching the web for exact same link on tutorialspoint I must rename it. May help noobs like me. lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These lines

```
-D1;                     // apply negation
-D2;                     // apply negation
```

do not do what you think they are doing. Let's say we have an `int` variable:

```
int var = 3;
-var; // What does this do?
```

What does this do? `-var` *evaluates* to `-3`, but does not *modify* `var` to be equal to `-3`. If you want to modify `var`, you assign to it as you normally would:

```
var = -var; // Now var == -3
```

Same deal with your `Distance` type. `-D1` does not modify `D1`, and it *should* not modify it since that is not what the unary `operator-` is expected to do. Simply assign the negative version back to itself, like so:

```
D1 = -D1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your unary negation operator *returns* the new `Distance` object, it doesn't modify the existing object.

You should do e.g.

```
Distance D3 = -D1;
D3.displayDistance();
```

Comment: What if I want to change the existing one?

Comment: @VidorVistrom Just assign back to it, like `D1 = -D1`

Comment: @VidorVistrom Then you need to write code to do that. But usually a unary negation operator shouldn't modify the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You return the new object but dont use it to store anywhere.

You should do `D1 = -D1;`